# In JQuery UI autocomplete how do I change elements classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

The autocomplete is outputting data in this format:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <a class="ui-corner-all">item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <a class="ui-corner-all">item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <a class="ui-corner-all">item 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

where do I change it to make it output it this way:

```
<ul class="pageitem">
  <li class="menu">
    <a class="name">item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu">
    <a class="name">item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu">
    <a class="name">item 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

? I even tried to change the jquery script, but it's too complex for me hehe, what do I need to change?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why are you using jQuery UI in the first place then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should't change the classes. jQuery UI uses the classes not only for styling but as selectors to make its widgets work so, if you change them, you no longer have a working plugin.

Depending on your needs, if you need to style the select at your own will, you should edit the css file provided by jQuery, or add classes of your own.

I repeat, don't remove those classes...

If you want to add a span to the LIs, after the anchor, use the callback 'open', something  like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "autocompleteopen", function(event, ui) {   
   $(this).find('li.ui-menu-item').each(function(index){
      var span = $('<span>');
      $(span).text('whatever you want');
      $(this).append($(span)); 
   });
});
```

Comment: Yea I can live with that, but how do I add things to it ? like if I want it to output an extra <span> in the list?

Comment: Use add class like what former mentioned. and skip '.removeClass()'

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all').addClass('pageitem').removeClass('ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all');

$('.ui-menu-item').addClass('menu').removeClass('ui-menu-item');

$('.ui-corner-all').addClass('name').removeClass('ui-corner-all');
```

Comment: This is better;
`$('ul.ui-autocomplete').removeClass().addClass('pageitem');`

`$('.ui-menu-item').removeClass().addClass('menu');`

`$('.ui-corner-all').removeClass.addClass('name');`

Answer (score 0):

I was working in a template for opencart, and in a specific tpl, the **tracking.tpl** I had a problem with the autocomplete list position.

There can be very simple for who knows javascrit, bad I dont have a lot of knowledge about.

Was little hard found the point where it is generated.

Well, I got it. I did a search for it: **zIndex(this.element.zIndex()+1).css({top:0,left:0})** in the **jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js** only change the top and left for change the position or what you need.

I know, its very simple bad not so simple to found.

I hope this can help the others with the same problem.